# Does omitting "by" change the meaning of the "by yourself" expression?

Tags: prepositions

Would the question "Did you take this photo by yourself?" have the same meaning if we omitted "by" or would the meaning be somewhat altered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To **do something by yourself** means you had **no help** doing it.

To **do something yourself**, means **someone else did not do it**.

That's the difference.